# Android Bluetooth InputStream.available() Buffer

Tags: android, bluetooth, inputstream

In an effort to implement the simplest, most responive non-blocking way of detecting the continuity of the bluetooth connection between my arduino nano (persistent bluetooth client) and android phone (always listening bluetooth server), I am using

```
    int bytesAvailable = InputStream.available();
```

to periodically determine if there is any data on the InputStream.

It's worth saying that I have no important information to transfer over the bluetooth connection. I'm just implementing a 'ping' (the digit 1 in fact) to the phone every second or so.

If 'bytesAvailable' stays the same for 3 consecutive samples (appx 3.6 seconds) then I'm assuming the connection is lost and closing the btServerSocket and btSocket in readiness for a re-connection by the client. Despite all the warnings that .available() is unreliable, it works surprisingly well and avoids having to use

```
    InputStream.read();
```

which takes ages (sometimes 10 seconds) to realise the connection has been lost.

The problem I am having is that after a particular number of sampling cycles (approx 330) the 'connection is lost' part of the code kicks in because 'bytesAvailable' reaches a plateau for three consecutive samples. It looks like a buffer has filled. My LogCat entires prove the bytesAvailable value 'maxes out'. I have changed the code to allow 100 consecutive values and the bytesAvailable value never increases beyond this same max value.

How can I either:

- set a large buffer size for .available() without needing to use .read()
- or flush() the InputStream to allow it to start from zero again

Or is there a better logical approach?

Comment: Read from the buffer. Checking the amount of bytes available doesn't remove the data from the buffer, you will actually have to read it. If available returns something, I would simply read the byte.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. That does indeed work but I was hoping there was another way.

Comment: There is if you know the type of the input stream; some streams have an input flush method. So all you would have to do is simply upcast and then call flush after available. That said, that is really not a safe of way of programming; the library could change the underlying stream unbeknownst to you. Not likely, but it can happen.